# How can I set up and run a very simple php-apache server in a docker container that's already using another image?

Tags: java, php, apache, docker, dockerfile

I'm tasked with creating a very simple, web browser accessible gui that can run a specific java file within a docker container. To do this I've chosen to set up a php-apache server that serves an index.php document with the gui. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

This gets the gui (index.php is inside the src folder) I've written up and running no problem, but it cannot access and run the required java files (obviously, since this creates a separate container).

**The Question:**

How can I set up a php-apache server inside the existing Dockerfile (provided below) doing the same thing as the Dockerfile above? My aim is to run the java file using php scripts and display the result to the user.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["./build/libs/*.jar", "./fooBar.jar"]
ENV JAVA_OPTS=${FOO_JAVA_OPTS}
CMD ["/usr/bin/tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I have not written the java file myself, only being tasked with running specific commands using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no easy way of merging images like I initially hoped (You cannot have multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile). What I eventually ended up doing was to manually merge the two images ([openjdk](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/b8ce9eff38451de3282b2eb2bcd8b520fb95e1ce/8/jre/slim/Dockerfile) and [php](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a5c895da277a71578af9561b0e282e6cb0764434/7.3/stretch/apache/Dockerfile)) into something like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home
RUN ln -svT "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" /docker-java-home
ENV JAVA_HOME /docker-java-home/jre
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u212
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u212-b01-1~deb9u1
RUN set -ex; \
    if [ ! -d /usr/share/man/man1 ]; then \
        mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1; \
    fi; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jre-headless="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    [ "$(readlink -f "$JAVA_HOME")" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]; \
    update-alternatives --get-selections | awk -v home="$(readlink -f "$JAVA_HOME")" 'index($3, home) == 1 { $2 = "manual"; print | "update-alternatives --set-selections" }'; \
    update-alternatives --query java | grep -q 'Status: manual'

COPY ["./build/libs/*.jar", "./FooBar.jar"]
ENV JAVA_OPTS=${FOO_JAVA_OPTS}

COPY gui/src /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Both are Debian based images so the merging were relatively easy (I also removed much of the cluttering comments from the original image source) and since the openjdk image were simpler, I added it on top of the php image instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As it is Debian based images. one way of doing it, install packages in the container and create the new images from that.

```
root@310c94d8d75f:/usr/src/app# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"

2: root@310c94d8d75f:/usr/src/app# apt update

3- root@310c94d8d75f:/usr/src/app# apt install apache2
4- root@310c94d8d75f:/usr/src/app# apt install php
```

finally run :  docker commit

after this, you will get a new image with the mentioned name.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

2: you can add the same command in Dockerfile and rebuild.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["./build/libs/*.jar", "./fooBar.jar"]
ENV JAVA_OPTS=${FOO_JAVA_OPTS}
CMD ["/usr/bin/tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
RUN apt update && apt install apache2 -y && apt install php -y
```

Comment: I was searching for something like this, but it appears to be incomplete. With this you've installed php and apache on the container, but you must also run it (I assume?). I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: yes, what I mentioned in 2nd solution is an example of Dockerfile. you have to run build command. you will get new images.